# difference in declaration of member objects

Tags: c++, declaration

This is probably a very basic question but I never got around to understanding it properly. When I declare member variables I usually do within a class

```
class Bloke
   {
   public:
   Bloke(): age(24) {}
   int age;
   }
```

So, I usually declare after the semicolon the member variables with "membera(), memberb()" etc. Over time I got a bit lazy and started to also include declarations of the member variables directly in {}, that is

```
Bloke(){age=24;}
int age;
```

Or even outside the class in the constructor separately. Can someone please explain if this is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not wrong and up until c++11 it was the only way. Most people however would consider the first way to be easier and more idiomatic for c++11, it is called constructor delegation. In c++11 you can also do inline initialization for some types like this:

```
class Bloke
{
   public:
   Bloke():{}
   int age = 24;
};
```

The value for age will be 24 unless you change it somewhere else for all initialized objects. IMO constructor delegation should be used for any situation where applicable and save the body of the constructor for extra work.

Comment: I thought I don't have c++11 I am using MingW 3.4.5 - Is this c++11?

Comment: @user2856452 not familiar with that compiler, but I'm pretty sure you cannot do constructor delegation without c++11, either way my answer still applies

Comment: Interesting as when I try c++ syntax like double vectors with ">>" I have to have a space in between the "> >" and someone said in c++11 you can use >>. So I thought I don't have c++11

Comment: @user2856452 honestly I couldn't tell you if it supports c++11 but double >> is certainly not the defining factor of c++11

Comment: I am pretty sure I don't have c++11 as I have used both declarations interchangeably way before 2008. Someone told me at that time it is bad practice to declare not with :member(24) but I don't remember why he mentioned that.

Comment: @user2856452 ok well it's definitely a c++11 feature, but I suppose either MingW 3.4.5 has an extension or you have been using magic compilers for the past 5 years :)

Comment: I keep it for now without the c++11 tag. If this thing clears we can put the tag on. I am interested to know perhaps a bit about performance issues here as well or exceptions.

Comment: @user2856452 it's really just syntactic sugar, but it looks more correct because it implies the object is being **constructed** right there, this has nothing to do with exceptions